# Phonegap jQuery ajax request does not work

Tags: jquery, cordova

I want to develop a Phonegap application and I am using jQuery Mobile. I am developing and testing via Firefox on the PC, so the issues described here don't have anything todo with Phonegap - this is an Firefox PC issue:

The following code  does not work and I would need some help to point me in the right direction:

```
var loadWeather = function()
{
    // Request absetzen
    $.ajax(
    {
        // the URL for the request
        url : 'http://www.google.com/ig/api',

        // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
        data : {
            weather : 'Vienna'
        },

        // whether this is a POST or GET request
        type : 'GET',

        // the type of data we expect back
        dataType : 'xml',

        // code to run if the request succeeds; the response is passed to the function
        success : function(xml)
        {
            parseXML(xml);
        },

        // code to run if the request fails;
        // the raw request and status codes are passed to the function
        error : function(xhr, status)
        {
            alert('Error retreiving weather!');
        }
    });
}
```

status is "error", xhr.readyState=0, xhr.status=0, so I don't get any info for the reason from jQuery at all. The request is executed, the answer-header (from Firebug) is:

```
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.google.com
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
```

and 200 OK. So why I am jumping in the error case? xhr.isRejected() says true. What does this mean?

Comment: instead on XML try JSONP

Comment: You will not be able to test it (with real requests, without some proxy script) due to Cross domain origin restrictions. This API doesn't seem to support JSONP. But it's going to work inside Phonegap on the device since there are no cross domain restictions.

Comment: @dfsg: if your comment would have been an answer, I would have selected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so there are a number of things going on here. First Firefox won't allow you to do a cross domain request using AJAX so that is why you are getting the error case when you try it from your desktop browser.

If you were testing on the device I would suspect that jQuery would be giving your a successful result. You see when running code from the file:// protocol on a mobile device the same origin policy does not apply. In fact I've done an AJAX query to that exact Google API in a sample app I developed with PhoneGap.

However, depending on the version of jQuery you are using there may be a bug. Frequently when you do an AJAX request from the file:// protocol the xhr.status coming back will be '0'. That is actually okay and should be treated the same as a '200' but I believe older version of jQuery have an issue with the 0 status.

I've written a quick blog post on doing XHR from a PhoneGap application that you can read:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

It takes jQuery completely out of the equation. If that doesn't work then nothing will.

Comment: But when I do the Firefox test I also use the file:// protocol, so I expected that Firefox will allow me to perform the request. I also see the request on the Firebug network page.

Comment: But you are right. It works on Phongap on the device and that is what counts. So I am not able to test/debug on Firefox or Chrome, but have to run it on the device without a possibility to debug.

Comment: Correct the mobile browsers work differently than the desktop browsers when it comes to AJAX. You can read up on how to do cross domain ajax in Firefox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control. Debugging on device or emulator can be done using debug.phonegap.com.