# Ajax call on phonegap not sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am pulling my hair out on this one.

I have a jquery ajax call to my server that works on my browser, it works on my device when I have it connected to my local proxy for http sniffing, but just hangs when it's off my proxy on the wifi or on the cell network.

I've set up the phonegap config.xml to allow my domain.  The request is a get on the server as well as the ajax call. You'll notice it's jsonP.

The call is straight forward jquery, I'll post the code anyway.  The *api* object is a custom object I made to hold the application's functionality.

```
var dfd = $.ajax({
    url: myurl, // I've confirmed the url, but prefer to keep it private
    data: {
        ApplicationID: api.applicationID,
        DeviceID: api.device.uuid(),
        OSVersion: api.device.version(),
        DeviceVersion: api.device.platform(),
        Lat: lat,
        Lng: lng,
        Bearing: bearing
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 30000
})
.fail(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    console.error(jqXHR);
});
```

I've tried this answer, the closest I could find to my problem, but it doesn't seem to work.
[Phonegap jQuery ajax request does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924482/phonegap-jquery-ajax-request-does-not-work)

Is there something I'm missing?  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention, the timeout I have set on the ajax call does nothing, it just seems to ignore it.

Comment: Set your cordova.xml to have `<access origin=".*"/>` and retry, post your results.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the access origin is already set to allow the app.  <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />

Comment: In your OQ you have **config.xml** set, but I am talking of **cordova.xml**

Comment: I must have missed the spelling in your reply. I'm not aware of cordova.xml, or that it was even an option.  How does it differ from the config.xml?

Comment: The whitelisting rules are found in `res/xml/cordova.xml` ... from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Thanks.  The part I'm not understanding is why is there a config.xml and a cordova.xml.  I already have whitelisting rules in one, how does the other come into play?  Or in different words, why is a cordova config file necassary to the config?  I'm just trying to understand the issue, I'll try your solution as soon as I get back in front of the code.

Comment: I think, that the whitelisting belongs into cordova.xml - config.xml has nothing to do with it. AFAIK there is no need (or use) for a config.xml in newer versions of Cordova, "the framework formerly known as phonegap"

Comment: Eugen - the Phonegap 'Getting Started' page (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) says to copy the /xml folder from the Cordova build to /res. This contains config.xml which mentions white listing in it. However am I right to believe that this is an incorrect configuration (and thus the release is missing cordova.xml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was entirely different.  My dependencies were not loading because of how the mobile browsers add AMD scripts.  I've fixed this by consolidating all scripts into a single file and it's worked ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pull a json string, why not use

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com?jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){ ... }
```

Note the jsoncallback. What happens here is that jquery parses an extra parameter to the code to verify the result is from the actual request. This happens on cross-domain requests.

To make your 'json-builder' compatible, simple place the jsoncallback in front of the request:

```
$return =  $_GET["jsoncallback"].'({"title" : "test", "author" : "someone"});
```

Comment: getJson just uses $.ajax under the hood.  There is no clear difference.  The live server reads the call fine when it's on the browser or through a proxy, so I know it's not how the call is formatted on the server.  This error only springs up when the phone is by itself, with only a wifi or cell connection.

Comment: I know it is the same (was not sure about $.ajax having a jsoncallback though). If you have your cordova access a http:// it should work, but when you run the javascript from the phone (assets/www) it is on another domain, and you need to provide the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may not be, as you mentioned, cross domain. Does your server logs any requests? I have similar problem with second (the same) request after linking it from index.html, first request works fine. I found an information that it may be a phonegap bug.

Comment: Yes, my server does log requests.  That's how I know it's never hitting my server at all.  Unfortunately, none of my requests work.  So far, I've not tested this on android, only on ios.