# Ajax request in Phonegap not working

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have been facing this issue, where the AJAX request sent from application does not seem to work. 
Currently this phonegapp is for Android, I am trying to run the sample in Android Emulator with Eclipse.

1) The FAILURE callback is getting called every time.

2) The status code is always 0 and responseText is null.

I have gone through many links and questions but none of them helped.

[Phonegap jQuery ajax request does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924482/phonegap-jquery-ajax-request-does-not-work).

I have also change CONFIG.xml with origin="*"  temporarily.
Then CONFIG.xml under resources to origin=".*"

Here is the sample code snippet that I am using.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.0.189/gcm/register.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

              console.log("Ajax Success : " + textStatus);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log(xhr.responseText + " Status : " + xhr.status);

        }
    });
```

Response Text comes as null
Status as 0

Comment: could you provide more details? Some code perhaps?

Comment: @MehernoshBhathena I have added the code snippet

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem with the syntax of your snippet. Can you paste this into your console and see if it works: 
`$.ajax({url: "http://api.jquery.com/",type: 'POST',data: {s:'ajax'},beforeSend: function() {},success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {console.log("Ajax Success : " + textStatus);},error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(xhr.responseText + " Status : " + xhr.status); }});`

Comment: @MehernoshBhathena I should have mentioned, the call syntax is correct, it works in console, the url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems awkward, but I changed the method POST to GET on both the server side and the client script with ajax and it started working.

I hope this helps someone who has struggled a lot like me.